# How to paint title bar window only?

Tags: winapi, mfc

As mention from microsft doc. WM_NCPAINT is use to paint non-client area. it means like title bar. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint. But i get unexpected result. it paint client area too. and the weird one. title bar is gone. when launch. after ALT+TAB. the title bar appears with windows 7 style in windows 10.

```
class CMainFrame::CFrameWnd
{
  public:
    CMainFrame()
    {
      Create(
        NULL, 
        "Hello World!", 
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU, 
        CRect(CPoint(100, 100), CSize(640, 360));
    }
  protected:
    afx_msg void OnNcPaint();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
}
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
ON_WM_NCPAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMainFrame::OnNcPaint()
{
  PAINTSTRUCT ps;
  CBrush brush;
  brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
  CDC *pDC = BeginPaint(&ps);

  pDC->FillRect(&ps.rcPaint, &brush);

  EndPaint(&ps);
}

class CApplication : public CWinApp {
   BOOL InitInstance() {
      CMainFrame* mainWnd = new CMainFrame();
      m_pMainWnd = mainWnd;

      mainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
      mainWnd->UpdateWindow();
      
      return TRUE;
   }
};
```

Comment: From [BeginPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint): *"An application should not call `BeginPaint` except in response to a `WM_PAINT` message."* You are violating that contract. The documentation for [WM_NCPAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint) explains how to get a properly clipped device context.

Comment: @IInspectable after searching read there and there. WM_NCPAINT will pain as hell to override all default title bar functionality. And will broken the default theme. after thinking. my solution is just add a line to seperate client area with non-client area. how to do this? like explorer. https://ibb.co/fkShc8M. for now i just think add a control window that mimic one line. But i think theres proper way

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for the reply, i succefull to add frame border in top already to seperate non-client with client.

Answer (score 1):

In `InitInstance`, you must call the base class `CWinApp::InitInstance()` in the first line.

Create your main frame window using

```
CreateEx(0, AfxRegisterWndClass(0), "Hello World!",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 640, 360, NULL, 0);
```

Add `PreCreateWindow` to control the edges and other properties

```
int CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    auto res = CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs);
    cs.dwExStyle &= ~WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
    return res;
}
```

Use the appropriate paint classes, `CPaintDC dc(this)`, `CWindowDC`, for overriding `OnPaint` or `OnNcPaint` (avoid overriding `OnNcPaint`), use `CClientDC dc(this)` for other client area paints. Avoid calling WinAPI functions directly, for example avoid calling `BeginPaint`. You can also use Visual Studio to create a sample dialog based application, it will be easier to get started with that.